# How likely is a computer programmer to receive Long Term Disability (LTD) benefits?

Tags: united-states

A friend told me that, as a computer programmer in the United States, I should not buy long-term disability (LTD) insurance. He basically said that I could never receive benefits, because there is almost no physical ailment that could prevent me from doing my job. Is that correct?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for specific financial (insurance) advice

Comment: As stated it is a better fit for the personal finance stack, https://money.stackexchange.com/.  But there might be answers available from the _legal_ point of view, IDK.

Comment: Nothing in this question concerns the law or legal process. It is at best a request for information to support or reject an opinion on the usefulness of insurance, and belongs on Personal Finance SE (if anywhere).

Comment: Flagging for migration to workplace.se or personal finance stack.   Good question, wrong venue.

Comment: I’ve been a programmer for over forty years, but I have received long term disability more than once.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not about navigating at the workplace but rather a question seeking for legal/financial advise asking if an insurance would pay out..

Comment: This is a good question seeking a proper home.  Not sure why it wasn't migrated (from law) to money.stackexchange.com instead of here - but don't close it - move it it a better location. (money.se.com accepts questions on insurance, it's right in their topic list.)

Comment: @davidbak I think we need the OP to clarify which half of their friend's claim they're asking about. Are they asking whether there are any physical ailments that would prevent them from working or are they asking if there are any physical ailments the insurance would cover? The latter is a money question but the former is a health question.

Comment: @BSMP - well, he asked this question on the _Law_ stack so you can make an inference from that (maybe, maybe he just didn't know about these other stacks) - also he accepted an answer that ... well, could be interpreted _both_ ways maybe ... hmmm.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a *good personal* disability policy that has strong *own occupation coverage*. Like doctors get. And disability policies like that don't just cover *physical* ailments like knee problems. They cover *cognitive* problems too. In addition to what Ron mentions - consider *stroke* (major or minor), any illness or injury that leaves you with temporary or permanent head pain, any illness or injury that leaves you with temporary or permanent brain damage, mental illness of moderate to strong severity (which can develop at any age for many reasons beyond your control) - these things can happen to programmers for sure.

Group disability policies typically have *any* occupation coverage: Can you sit on a stool and say "would you like fries with that?"  You're not disabled: get a job, case closed.  Some group coverage (I've seen it in high-tech) and some less expensive personal policies have weak own occupation coverage: "So, you've been working as a neurosurgeon, can't do that anymore, yes, I get it, but: how about reviewing patient files for an insurance company to see if it should pay for a procedure - you've been trained to do *that* so off you go!  Yes, I get that the pay is significantly lower, what's your point?  Off you go!" Or it might have a time limit: "Yes, we paid you for 3 years because you can no longer do neurosurgery but now that gravy train is over, Walmart is hiring greeters - no more checks for you!"  So you've got to make sure you're getting what you think you're getting when you purchase this.

(Other tips are available around the web on what else to look for in these policies.)

w.r.t. short-term disability: that depends entirely on the state of your bank account and savings and how long you're willing to draw down on that in case you're out of work for weeks (maybe, say, [vestibular neuritis](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/15227-vestibular-neuritis) knocks you out for between 2-3 months (*or longer*) - *that's* a "physical" disease that programmers can get (ask me how I know)).

The cognitive reasons I mentioned above are *what I fear most* and are why, as a programmer, I've had a personal long-term disability policy for over 3 decades.

Comment: Oh by the way, since this is the _law_ stack exchange, and to make this Q&A slightly more on topic: Attorneys, as well as doctors, can make use of disability coverage for the same reasons.... (just with even _less_ sympathy from the insurance company adjuster ...)

Comment: +1 fearing cognitive problems the most. I'm going to specifically highlight **mental illness** as an important, if not *the* most important, disabler of programmers. A policy that covers this is critical. Hard-core burnout (and other clinical conditions) means you can't do your job, and this is no different from (hopefully temporary) brain damage.

Comment: @obscurans - very good, though for reasons related to my personality I, myself, refuse to even _consider_ the _possibility_ of _anything of the kind_ affecting me, myself - thus its absence from being mentioned in the first paragraph above.

Comment: Lol you managed to make it way too deadpan for the cognition I have left. There's a huge loss of context from not hearing the delivery in person.

Comment: anyway, it was a good point, i've edited the answer to include it

Answer (score 31):

No, I'm a programmer and I have LTD and STD insurance. What happens if your hands get maimed? Go blind? Major back problems preventing you from sitting? Paralysis? I can think of a ton of things that would keep me from programming...

There is no law that would prevent you from buying LTD insurance as a programmer.

Comment: I'm sure some scummy insurance company out there would say something "You don't need hands, use text to speech" or "You don't need to sit, you can lay on the couch and program on a laptop".  Remember insurance companies only make money when you DON'T collect.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, that's ... optimistic.  Is this person young? They infamously have a false sense of being immortal.

Many co-workers (and half the people I dated) back in the day, had disabilities which constricted their computer use. Pay attention to your own circle of friends - I bet there are more than you noticed, they just don't talk about it much.

There are a variety of such injuries or conditions, *and some are occupationally induced*.

Read my lips. **Some are *caused* by using computers**.

That's why on any mid-size or larger enterprise, there will be an Ergonomics Team who will try to nanny you about the layout of your workstation.  I'm sure you find those people trite and annoying, but they're trying to prevent what did happen to my sweetie, who had to go on permanent disability due to getting carpal tunnel *due to bad ergonomics*.  There was a civil judgment, but it was poor due to the difficulty of proving causality.

So yes, it can happen, and you can even do it to yourself (or an employer can do it to you).

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: disability insurance is not necessarily for being unable to work forever, it is meant to be a stopgap for being unable to work some amount of time. (Ultimately, your friend is incorrect)

This is a theme throughout, figured I'd add it to the beginning too: all numbers and policy interactions are examples, check the policies offered.

Private disability insurance is meant to cover you being unable to work for some amount of time. STD is for you being out up to 2 months (for example). LTD is meant for longer outages (when a claim starts may depend on you having STD: if you have STD, LTD starts after it expires; if you don't, LTD starts after 6 months (all examples, read the policies)).

For example, let's say you have an accident that causes you to miss 8 months of work (but the damage won't prevent you returning to work).

- STD+LTD: you start collecting STD in a week, covers you for 2 months, then LTD starts, covers you for the remaining 6 months, then you go back to work.
- just STD: start collecting in a week, collect for 2 months, get nada for 6 months, go back to work.
- just LTD: get nada for 6 months, get LTD for 2 months, return to work.

That is idealized though, there's good reasons that insurance companies are as reviled as they are =\

Shamelessly stealing this from other answers (for completeness): Depending on policy, it may cover mental health conditions preventing you working.

Comment: This. Not all disabilities are permanent. I got stage 4 metastatic melanoma and I couldn't work at all for about a year, and my husband couldn't work much either. The STD and LTD payments meant one less thing to worry about, and we could concentrate on recovery. My LTD is not great and will end after 5 years, but at this point I have figured out how to work with the permanent effects of the treatment that "cured" the cancer.